# How do i Import a rows from one Google Sheet to another with filter?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I have a Google Form, the answers go to Google Sheets.
I want to import answers from sheets (Аnswer) into new sheets but with a filter applied.
For example: from sheets (answer) into a new table, I import answers only from 100 REPPM.
For this I use the following formula:
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE ("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dMo6F1CTxAaEx1bS2NEu4kIu5hJTCBbCt13AV2E_f2w/edit#gid=1390527531","Answer 1!A:E"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 Where Col2 Matches '"&100 REPPM&"'")`

My formula is incorrect, please help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

To copy those rows from one spreadsheet file to another, use this:

`=query(importrange("1dMo6F1CTxAaEx1bS2NEu4kIu5hJTCBbCt13AV2E_f2w", "Answer 1!A1:E"), "where Col2 = '100 REPPM' ", 1)`

To copy those rows from one tab to another within the same spreadsheet file, you should not use `importrange()`. Instead, use a regular range reference, like this:

`=query('Answer 1'!A1:E, "where B = '100 REPPM' ", 1)`

In the event your spreadsheet is in a locale that uses semicolons as formula argument separators, replace commas `,` in the above formulas with semicolons `;`.

Comment: Thanks for trying!
But it still doesn't work. syntax error in formula(.

IMPORTRANGE is needed. Because I am transferring rows to another google sheets.
Who has more thoughts?

Comment: The formulas in the answer are syntactically correct. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Comment: The correct formula is=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1dMo6F1CTxAaEx1bS2NEu4kIu5hJTCBbCt13AV2E_f2w"; "Answer!A1:E15"); "select * where (Col2='100 REPPM')")

Comment: Right. If your spreadsheet is in a locale that uses semicolons as formula argument separators, you will need to use semicolons rather than commas. The `select *` clause and the parentheses in the `where` clause can be omitted. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)